# How to return custom response in Spring with several attributes other than the List<Entity>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to get a custom response back from a spring rest controller back to the user, containing a list of all registered users and other keys such as sucess, etc.
I tried the following approach but the Json array is completly escaped as a string...

```
@GetMapping(value = "/workers", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<String> getAllWorkers() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject resp = new JSONObject();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    HttpStatus status;
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        List<Worker> workers = workerservice.getAllworkers();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(workers);
        
        resp.put("success", true);
        resp.put("info", json);
        status = HttpStatus.OK;
    } catch (Error | JsonProcessingException e) {
        resp.put("success", false);
        resp.put("info", e.getMessage());
        status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resp.toString(),status);
}
```

I get something like this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "info": "[ {\n  \"id\" : 3,\n  \"password\" : \"abcdefg\", \n  \"tasks\" : [ ], (...) ]"
}
```

and wanted something like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "info": [ 
        {
           "id" : 3,
           "password" : "abcdefg",
           "tasks" : [ ]
        },
        (...) 
    ]"
}
```

Is there any way I can get the json array properly showed after a request?

Comment: When you send the response Spring will create the Json object. You should probably just take the worker list directly and let Spring do the serialization. No need to write it to a string yourself.

Comment: How can I add The List<workers> along with the custom attributes in a responseEntity?

Comment: Create a custom response POJO with the fields you need, such as the worker list. Let your controller return ReaponseEntity<YourResponsePojo>. Some annotations might be required in the pojo to give the desired output. Check out Jackson JSON annotations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can let Spring Boot handle the serialization of the response entity.

Create a POJO which defines your response object.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class WorkerPojo {
    @JsonProperty("success")
    private boolean success;
    @JsonProperty("info")
    private List<Worker> workerList;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    // A default constructor is required for serialization/deserialization to work
    public WorkerPojo() {
    }
    
    // Getters and Setters ....
}
```

This lets you simplify your getAllWorkers method a bit:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/workers", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<WorkerPojo> getAllWorkers() throws JSONException {
    WorkerPojo response;
    try {
        List<Worker> workers = workerservice.getAllworkers();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new WorkerPojo(true, workers, "OK"), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Error e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new WorkerPojo(false, null, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Note that I added a separate message field for the error message. I find that clients are much happier if a specific field is not used for different types of data. "info" should never be anything else than a list of workers and "message" should never be anything else than a String.

Disclaimer: I didn't have a Spring Boot project setup to test this properly. If something is not working let me know and I will check it.